# Discrepancy between table frequencies and histogram ... geom_histogram rounds down?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, frequency, cut

Say I have the following dataframe sample:

```
df <- structure(list(Day = c("Wed", "Wed", "Thu", "Wed", "Thu", "Sat"
), `After hours (hours)` = c(3, 1.7, 1.6, 2.1, 3.2, 0.6)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

When I create the following histogram:

```
ggplot(df, aes(as.numeric(`After hours (hours)`))) +
     geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5, fill = "white", color = "black")
```

Why do I end up with a bar of count 1 for the range 0 h to 0.5 h if none of my data should fit into that hour range? Subsequently, I get 0 for the 0.5 h to 1.0 h range. Does R round up to integers for histograms? Why isn't the 0.6 in my data being placed there? How can I fix this?

Comment: @joran Thank you very much for clarifying

Comment: @Andrea It's also useful to use the "boundary" argument to determine where the first bin starts. Try `geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5, fill = "white", color = "black", boundary = 0)`.

Comment: @Andrea Also, adding `+ scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 4))` makes the graph easier to read and process.

Comment: @user2363777 Thank you, that's quite helpful!